# Show/hide div with var linked to the 1st one

Tags: jquery

I'd like to click a div (with song name), then it is replaced by a new one with player embedded (playing the song clicked). My script is ok to show/hide the divs, but I can't get the variable from the first one to select player on the second one. (I get the informations from json file - soundcloud - which contain `item.uri` parameter that is necessary for player code.

My html:

```
<div id="resultats_son_div">
    <input type="text" name="titre_son" size="20" maxlenght="255" id="titre_son" class="texte_titre_son" placeholder="Titre du morceau">
    <div class="resultats_son" id="resultats_son"></div>
</div>
<div id="player_son" class="player_son_cache">Player I want to display</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#titre_son").keyup(function(e){
       var q = $("#titre_son").val();
       $.getJSON("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?callback=?", {
           q: q,
           client_id: "4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498",
           limit: "10"
       },
       function(data) {
           $("#resultats_son").empty();
           $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var str = item.title;
            var str_clean=str.replace(/'/g,"\'");
              $("#resultats_son").append("<div class='titre_morceau' id='titre_morceau'><a href='#' onclick='return false;' class='lien_son' id='lien_son'>" + str_clean + "</a></div>");
//            $("#player_son").append("<iframe class='iframe' width='487' height='465' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=" + item.uri + "&amp;auto_play=false&amp;auto_advance=false&amp;buying=false&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;start_track=0&amp;callback=true'></iframe>");
           });
       });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#resultats_son_div').show(); //Show first div on page load
    $('#player_son').hide(); //Hide second div on page load
    $('#resultats_son').click(function(){
        $ ('#resultats_son_div').hide(); //Hide first div on click event
        $ ('#player_son').show(); //Show second div on click event
        return false;
    });
});
```

How could I do that please?

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/cqNwe/

Comment: which variable do you want?

Comment: I want to bring the item.uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$('#player_son').show();` you have to find the inner elements of the `div` that you click on. You can do that like this `$(this).find('a').html()`

Replace your `$('#player_son').show();` with `$ ('#player_son').html($(this).find('a').html()).show();`

Comment: Ok, works nice to get the content, but I'd like to bring item.uri (not present in the song text), how to keep it hidden and bring it to the new div?

Comment: I dont see any item.uri in your jsonresult and i dont know how the API works but I would guess you have to do another query for the div you click on.

Comment: I put the example here with item.uri : http://jsfiddle.net/cqNwe/22/
But oof course I don't want it visible...

Comment: found something quite good: http://jsfiddle.net/cqNwe/23/
but now I need to put it on the iframe tag: <iframe class='iframe' width='487' height='465' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=" + item.uri + "&amp;auto_play=false&amp;auto_advance=false&amp;buying=false&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;start_track=0&amp;callback=true'></iframe>

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to disturb you again ;-)
I can't comme back one I'm in the new div. I'd like to click on a button (in my case a picture - it works on my example), then return to the list, and then click on an other song to have ahain the player but with the new song. The return is ok, but when I click on a new song, the div appearing is the same, the content has not changed... Any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/cqNwe/25/